# How to add a family map to my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, treeview, family-tree

And Now I want to develop a iphone app, and will to add a view to show a family map, just like : and then will show a view just like : photos with some lines to show my falimy releationship, and how can I develop it , and can someone give me some advice  or help ? thank you very much!!!

map just like:

```
   my father           my mother         my wife(or husband)  parents

 my brothers(sisters)    ME              my wife(or husband)   his(or her)brothers(..)

                    my childrens              my childrens
```

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question you're asking. Do you want to *create* an iPhone app (for sale on the Apple store), or are you looking for an app already made that does all these things?

Comment: sorry， I　want to develop a iphone app ,and in this app have a function that show a family tree view , and I have no idear about it . and someone have some idea about it or some open soucecode about this function, thank you!!!

Comment: can you elaborate your question little more

Comment: sorry , maybe my question is little confusing, and my function just like here<http://spysee.jp/>, and a family map with some line to connect each other between them.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little confusing. But if you are looking for creating treeview inside an iPhone then you can get it [here](https://github.com/LaTtEX/MyTreeViewPrototype)

Comment: sorry , maybe my question is little confusing, and my function just like here<http://spysee.jp/>, and a family map with some line to connect each other between them.